# What exactly happens when the L1 cache copies a value from the L2 cache

Tags: caching, cpu

Lets say i have a cpu with the inclusive cache policy and i load a value that is only in the L2 cache and not in the L1.

Does it copy just that one value from the L2 and replace the "oldest" value in the L1 cache? Or does it load a entire cacheline?